# Django 1.6 UpdateView, losing PK on POST

Tags: python, django

I am trying to build an `UpdateView` for the `django.contrib.auth.User` class in Django 1.6.1. The `UpdateView` reuses a create template and uses an `UpdateForm` which redacts unnecessary fields. An admin is supposed to use this `UpdateView` to update the username and email of all the other users on the system.

I can navigate to the form by specifying the user PK in the URL field. That means I reach a page with the edit form populated with user details as specified by the PK. However, when I submit the form, Django takes me to an update url without the user PK, which throws a 404.

```
# urls.py

url(r'^update/(?P<pk>[\d]+)$', UpdateUserView.as_view(), name='update_user'),

# views.py

class UpdateUserView(UpdateView):
    model = User
    form_class = UpdateForm
    template_name = "create_user.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy('manage_users')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(UpdateUserView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        instance = None
        user_pk = self.kwargs.get('pk')

        context['submit_name'] = 'Update Order'

        if user_pk:
            instance = get_object_or_404(User, pk=user_pk)

        if self.request.POST:
            context['form'] = UpdateForm(self.request.POST, instance=instance)
        else:
            context['form'] = UpdateForm(instance=instance)
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        form = context['form']

        if form.is_valid():
            return redirect(reverse_lazy('manage_users'))
        else:
            return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))

# forms.py

class UpdateForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("username","email")

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UpdateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_class = 'form-create'
        self.helper.form_method = 'post'
        self.helper.form_action = '.'

        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Fieldset(
                '',
                Field('username', css_class='form-control'),
                Field('email', css_class='form-control'),
            ),
            ButtonHolder(
                Submit('submit', 'Update User')
            ),
        )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `action="."` for your form, but that strips the primary key from the url because the url pattern does not have a trailing slash.

You can either add a trailing slash to your url pattern

```
/update/(?P<pk>[\d]+)/$
```

or change your form's action in your form helper:

```
self.helper.form_action = ""
```

or to be explicit:

```
self.helper.form_action = reverse('update_user', args=(self.instance.pk,))
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! Adding a trailing slash did work, but I'm not sure why I *didn't* have to add a trailing slash to an UpdateView of one of my other apps that essentially does the same thing. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: `action="."` means use the current directory, which for `/update/5` is `/update/`, and for `/update/5/` is `/update/5/` Without seeing your other app's code, I can't tell you why it worked.